# Applying filter to my store causes grid to refresh with incorrect data set temporarily

Tags: javascript, datagrid, extjs, filter, extjs4

I have a very simple interface containing a grid, a search field, a search button and a data store from a JSON data source.

The default state of the grid is showing all the data for the given user and entering a term in the search field and clicking the search button applies a filter which then re-executes a call to fetch a new JSON result set and put that data in the grid.  I'm doing so the following way:

```
quick_search: function(search_term, store) {                                                                                                                                    
  store.clearFilter(true);                                                                                                                                                      
  store.filter([{property: 'filter', value: search_term}]);                                                                                                                     
}
```

The following function is executed just fine when the search button is clicked, but I'm seeing this scenario:

- User starts with 100 records in the grid
- User searched for "test" (has 25 records)
- The appropriate 25 records show in the grid
- User then searches for "stack" (45 results)
- **The grid quickly shows the original 100 records momentarily and then shows the correct 45 records**

And when that last step occurs, it's a very quick blip.

Is this the correct pattern for re-freshing grid data on the fly in a search-esque way?  Am I perhaps incorrectly clearing the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution...  Previous solution was trying to run load and was resulting in multiple requests back to my webserver fetching multiple result sets (first the incorrect, then the correct).

```
quick_search: function(search_term, store) {
  store.filters.clear();                                                                                                                                    
  store.filter([{property: 'filter', value: search_term}]);                                                                                                                     
}
```